# Set Kendo Scheduler height to screen size

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

I have to set the height of a kendo scheduler to the height of the screen. There is the feature to set the height via the kendo, but it only allows int:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<TaskViewModel>()
  .Name("scheduler")
  .Date(DateTime.Now.Date)
  .Height(200) ...
```

and if I do not set it, it will just show me the whole schedule. 
I have tried to set the div to

```
<div style="height:100vh;">.....</div>
```

but it did not help.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var sch= $('#scheduler').data("kendoScheduler");
    sch.element.height($(window).height())
});
```

**View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<TaskViewModel>()
  .Name("scheduler")
  .Date(DateTime.Now.Date)....
```